# Get None instead of a string slice if an index range is not valid

Tags: rust

I want to check if a string starts with `"|<any char><any char>TD"`. I have already verified that the string only contains 0..9, a-z, A-Z, space, ',' and '*'.

Including the regex crate for such a task is too much overhead, instead I think I need something like

```
fn get_slice(s: &str, range: Range<usize>) -> Option<&str> {
    unimplemented!();
}
```

It can be used like:

```
let is_good_string: bool = 
  get_slice(s, (0..5)).map_or(false, |v: &str| &v[0..1] == "|" && &v[3..5] == "TD");
```

Are there any functions in the standard library similar to my `get_slice`? Is it possible to solve my task with the help of standard library  functions in some other way?

Comment: You are going to hurt yourself by slicing strings like that. See the book on [slicing strings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/strings.html#slicing).

Comment: @E_net4 I read about `str` slicing before. You mean I will have problem with utf-8? It is not problem in my case, because of I parse old protocol which work with ascii

Comment: It really sounds like you are writing a parser. Instead of hand-rolling it all, you may want to look into tools that allow you to write efficient parsers. A popular choice, nom, was specifically created for parsing binary file formats.

Comment: @Shepmaster it is not binary protocol, it is old text protocol. Messages are lines, splitted by '/', like `csv` for example, but number of field vary depending on the first field.

Comment: @user1244932 ASCII text **is** binary data, just a highly restricted subset of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with [E_net4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42976185/155423), but for posterity, the literal answer to your question is straight-forward:

```rust
use std::ops::Range;

fn get_slice(s: &str, range: Range<usize>) -> Option<&str> {
    if s.len() > range.start && s.len() >= range.end {
        Some(&s[range])
    } else {
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(get_slice("", 0..5), None);
    assert_eq!(get_slice("abc", 0..2), Some("ab"));
    assert_eq!(get_slice("abc", 2..5), None);
    assert_eq!(get_slice("abc", 1..2), Some("b"));
    assert_eq!(get_slice("abc", 2..3), Some("c"));
}
```

Although I'd avoid using this for string slices and use it only on regular slices, due to the UTF-8 nature of strings.

Comment: Is `s.len() > range.start` check necessary?  `Range` not check that `start <= end` during creation?

Comment: @user1244932 Using your local compiler to create a range where the start is greater than the end will answer your question much more quickly.

Comment: A small question: should `s.len() > range.end` be a `>=` because `range.end` is exclusive?

Comment: @AlienKevin I don't believe so, no. `0..2` would mean get the bytes starting at 0 (inclusive) up to but excluding 2. The means that two bytes (indices 0 and 1) should be returned, which is what the current implementation does. Can you provide an example that shows it is broken? That would make it easier to see what you mean.

Comment: @Shepmaster For example, you can't get a full slice of the string. So `get_slice("abc", 0..3)` returns `None` but it should return `Some("abc")`.

Comment: @AlienKevin ah, perfect, I understand now! Fixed, thank you!

Comment: I have no idea why but I'm still getting a panic on `Some(&[range])`: "thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'byte index 65 is not a char boundary; it is inside '\u{f0fc}' (bytes 64..67) of ...".

Answer (score 5):

> get None instead of slice if index range not valid

There is no function for that in the standard, that I know of.

> I want to check if string starts with "|<any char><any char>TD",

But for that goal, I propose a solution that is (in my opinion) more elegant than slicing:

```
fn is_good(s: &str) -> bool {
    if !s.starts_with('|') {
        return false;
    }
    let mut td_iter = s.chars().skip(3);
    (td_iter.next(), td_iter.next()) == (Some('T'), Some('D'))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=30cbe7748de97814d3584f3582ec1fe6&version=stable&backtrace=0). It is compatible with any UTF-8 string and will ensure that no panics occur from reading code points outside of string/character boundaries.

Comment: In my case, with ascii, I better use `str::slice_unchecked`, plus in this way it is too much code, if I write something like this for  each "header" check, I will be buried by tons of code.

Comment: @user1244932 then parameterize it for `T` and `D`?

Comment: @user1244932 On that I impose two recommendations. One of them is to generalize your function for other types of headers (maybe even use macros). The other one is to *be specific* about your context *in* the question, otherwise answers will not consider it.

Comment: @Shepmaster plus also position of `T` and `D` may vary, that's why I think that check of optional slice can fix code mess.

Comment: @E_net4 Sorry, the idea that data pure ascii was obvious for me, so I not mentioned in my question. I updated question.

Comment: The position may vary, you say? `let mut code_iter = s.chars().skip(offset);`. And if your pattern may vary in size, just `take(pattern.len()).collect()` to a string and compare. But then again, this is out of the question's scope.